# Flutter - build on iOS very slowly, how fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, flutter-ios-build

I have flutter's app. I run it app in debug mode on iPhone from Android Studio(on Mac). It is very slowly(about 10 minutes). if I run my project from xCode it is much faster - about a minute.

[image]

this is a "medium" project, it uses some firebase packages:

```
 firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
 firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
 firebase_remote_config: ^0.10.0+2
 firebase_core: ^1.3.0
```

but I did not find any problems on the net related to these plugins, only for cloud_firestore.
how can I determine what is the problem with the long build? any advice?

Comment: Same issue occurs in my flutter app but after a lot debugging and testing.. what we found is in debug mode it lags a bit but in live mode it works much better

Comment: build in debug mode takes 10 minutes(in android studio), in xCode it takes 1 minute. the difference is 10 times it is very inconvenient. i think this is my local problem and i want to fix it

Comment: It happens because Firebase package takes too much time for load dependencies and download pods for each first time run. If you try without Firebase package it runs within a 1-2 minutes.

Comment: The iOS app running in Android Studio will take time anyways. Try to run it in XCode whenever possible.

Comment: The best case scenario is running the iOS Apps from Xcode, Terminal or VSCode

Answer (score 1):

Try to add FirebaseFirestore github firebase sdk to your project's podfile under runner target as below:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.11.0'
end
```